# Can an SPL function call submit()?

Tags: infosphere-spl, ibm-streams

I'm trying to call submit() from an SPL function (that is called from a Custom operator), but it is not working.  It complains about the name of my stream:

```
submit({prop1=value1, prop2=value2}, MyStream);
```

> ERROR: An unknown identifier was referenced in the SPL program: MyStream

Is this supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not supported.  `submit()` can only be called inside the Custom operator, within its `onTuple`, `onPunct`, or `onProcess` clauses. It cannot be called from an SPL function.